# Verfiy physical device on web service

Tags: design, architecture, sql

The problem is quite simple really. I'm trying to create a site, where the user can add a physical device to a database. Every device has its own unique id, which is stored in the database. 
However, I want to make sure, that whoever types in the device id actually has access to the device, so that someone can't just type in a bunch of numbers and maybe get lucky.

To do this there is a button on the device, which makes a call to the webserver (HTTP). 
I thought doing it like this:

1. The user types in a device id
2. The user gets redirected to a "waiting" site, which checks the database every x seconds for new entries, and checks if they're a match to the device id.
3. When the button is pressed on the device, an entry gets made in the database which allows the user to continue from the "waiting" site.

The problem is, I don't know how to make the waiting site. As I see it, the way I have described step 2 above will create a lot of unnecessary calls to the database, so I was wondering how to do this effeciently?


Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to check the database every x seconds.  Just put a submit button on the waiting page and ask the user to click it after they've pressed the button on the device.

Comment: This is a good way to solve the database problem, but I feel it adds unnecessary UX components. I want the user to be able to navigate the system with ease which is why I would like this mundane task to be solved by the software - if it's possible of course.

Comment: Does the device have any sort of screen?

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Unfortunately no. There's only a button, accelerometer and wifi.

Comment: Well, your question says that they have to push the button on their device before they can *continue.*  I just assume that "continue" means that they eventually click a submit button somewhere.

Comment: What about [Websockets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org)? Waiting page does the request to the server to open a websocket. Server accept (or not). Client (waiting page) keep waiting for a web push notification. When server recives the confirmation from the device, send a push notification to the client through the websocket. At this point, client goes from waiting page to any other page. See also [WebPush](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/)

Comment: If there is no Ui on the device, how does one configure wifi?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how real-time adding a device should be, consider making the two processes disconnected. Pushing the button logs the id along with a timestamp. Registering an ID on the website logs the id along with another timestamp. Have a process check the pending registrations from the site against the pending devices and when they match, allow the user access by marking the device in the database as belonging to the user. This can easily be done with a job that runs at a given interval.

Alternatively, if this has to be semi-real time you can simply ask the user to first press the button on the device and check the registration once when the ID is entered on the website. If that fails, simply ask them to either wait and try again or push the button on the device again.